# Code bug Lambda expression

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I m trying to write an lisp function who test if a number is prime or not. I received lambda expression error (i ve searched previouslly answered questions related to this) but i cannot find the solution.

```
(defun prime(n) 
(    
  (defvar '(*ok* nil) (*i* nil) (*d* nil)  
  (setf *ok* 1)
     (loop for *i* from 1 to (sqrt n) do
       ( 
    (if (= (mod n *d*) 0)
            (setf *ok* 0))  
       )
     )
     (if (= *ok* 1)
            (format t "Numarul prim")
            (format t "Numarul nu este prim")
         )
 )
```

)

Comment: Here is a good Lisp intro book. Download the PDF for free:
https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~dst/LispBook/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't mean to sound rude but you **do** need to read a decent Common Lisp tutorial; your code is more like "you can code C in any language", with some "I didn't get the dynamic variable stuff" thrown in.

To show you what you actually want, here's how I would write your logic:

```
(defun prime (n)
  (if (loop
         for i from 2 to (sqrt n)
         when (zerop (mod n i)) return nil
         finally (return t))
      "Numarul prim"
      "Numarul nu este prim"))
```

Testing:

```
CL-USER> (loop
   for i from 2 to 20
   do (format t "~a ~a~%" i (prime i)))
2 Numarul prim
3 Numarul prim
4 Numarul nu este prim
5 Numarul prim
6 Numarul nu este prim
7 Numarul prim
8 Numarul nu este prim
9 Numarul nu este prim
10 Numarul nu este prim
11 Numarul prim
12 Numarul nu este prim
13 Numarul prim
14 Numarul nu este prim
15 Numarul nu este prim
16 Numarul nu este prim
17 Numarul prim
18 Numarul nu este prim
19 Numarul prim
20 Numarul nu este prim
NIL
```

---

**EDIT 1** - using a local variable:

```
(defun prime (n)
  (let ((is-prime t))
    (loop
       for i from 2 to (sqrt n)
       when (zerop (mod n i))
       do (setf is-prime nil))
    (if is-prime
       "Numarul prim"
       "Numarul nu este prim")))
```

---

**EDIT 2** - "how can I sum all these prime numbers"

Let's go back to a true function - in this case, a predicate that indicates if a number is prime (returns `t`) or not (returns `nil`):

```
(defun prime (n)
  (loop
     for i from 2 to (sqrt n)
     when (zerop (mod n i)) return nil
     finally (return t)))

CL-USER> (prime 2)
T
CL-USER> (prime 3)
T
CL-USER> (prime 4)
NIL
```

and a second function that collects all primes between a lower and an upper bound into a list:

```
(defun primes (pfrom pto)
  (loop
     for i from pfrom to pto
     when (prime i) collect i))

CL-USER> (primes 2 20)
(2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19)
```

then you just need to

```
CL-USER> (reduce '+ (primes 2 20))
77
```

Comment: ok. thank you for this answer but i need to do like c style algorithm without brakeing program when you just find a divider, and also i need to include if test at the end of program but i don t get it in lisp

Comment: In C you would also `break` out of the loop IIRC. I have added a version according to your description but I wouldn't do it that way.

Comment: how i can summ the sum o all these prime numbers?

Comment: See my update. On StackOverflow you are supposed not to expand your questions every now and then but create new questions instead. Also, if your initial question has been answered then please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. If not then please tell us what's missing.